# Ionic Storage undefined in promise?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, promise, ionic-storage

I have an Ionic 2 app that shows the user Items inside Packages in the form of a list. I created a function that retrieves the current Item index inside a Package, it is fired the user launches the app. It checks if the index name-value pair in Ionic Storage (internal) memory is null. In that case, the index is set to 0 and stored in both internal and working memory. Otherwise, the index is retrieved from internal memory and used to set working memory.

However, `self.storage.set(myString, '0');` in the code below throws the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined`. I checked using `console.dir` and indeed `self.storage` was undefined inside the `then(...);` block. Why is this, and how can I work around it?

**Imports, declarations, constructor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

declare var self: ItemStorageService;

@Injectable()
export class ItemStorageService {
    workingMemoryItems: Array<any>;
    workingMemoryIndex: number;
    packageIndex: number;

    constructor(public storage: Storage) {
        self = this;
        self.packageIndex = 0;

        self.initializeIndex().then(
            res => {
                console.log(res);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        )
    }
// Other methods including initializeIndex()
}
```

**InitializeIndex function**

```
public initializeIndex(): Promise<any> {
    console.dir(self.storage); // Returns Storage object
    var myString = 'index_item_package_' + self.packageIndex;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        self.storage.get(myString).then(
            val => {
                if ((val === null) || (val === 'null')) {
                    console.dir(self.storage); // Returns undefined
                    self.storage.set(myString, '0');
                    self.workingMemoryIndex = 0;
                    resolve('Working memory index not found and set to 0');
                } else {
                    self.workingMemoryIndex = val as number;
                    resolve('Working memory index found and set to ' + val);
                }
            },
            err => {
                self.storage.set(myString, 0);
                self.workingMemoryIndex = 0;
                reject('Working memory index not found and set to 0');
            }
        )
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `self`?

Comment: I'm declaring it just below my imports, and setting `var self = this;` in my constructor

Comment: Can you add that part to the question as well? And are you creating a new variable with `var` in constructor?  Shouldn't you be assigning to the variable you already declared?

Comment: My bad, I'm using the same variable. I added in my code for more clarity.

Comment: Arrow functions are lexically bound, you can just use `this` here.

Comment: I changed every instance of `self` to `this` and that fixed it! `console.dir` shows `this.storage` as defined both inside and outside the promise.. But I'm still confused as to why. I read that setting `self = this;` was a foolproof way of avoiding any scoping issues. How does my assignment break something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason why this happened is because the global variable `self` was declared at the top of every one of my pages and services. This means that when I was running `self.storage.get(myString)`, the constructor for `ItemStorageService` was running and re-initializing `self` to point at itself.

The solution to this is not to use `self` everywhere, but only where it's needed (like inside callback functions) and to make sure to set `self = this` as close to where it's used as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `self = this` and just use `this`.

Like :

`this.packageIndex = 0;` and `this.storage.get(myString).then(...`